# Entity Framework and MS Dynamics CRM Plugin

Tags: c#, entity-framework, plugins, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to use Entity Framework in CRM Plugin?

This is my DbContext and DbConfiguration:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(Config))]
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> ContactSet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class Config : DbConfiguration
{
    public Config()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

In plugin when I try to perform CRUD operations on ContactSet I get error:
`The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository' threw an exception.`

I tested this code in console app and it works.

Any advice or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

UPDATE

Contact is EF model not CRM entity.

Comment: Are you aware of the early bound generation available through the SDK?  There is a free XrmToolbox tool called [Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/wiki/Early-Bound-Generator) that uses the SDK's capabilities to generate early-bound objects you can use in your code, and it has some great features which minimize the pain you would encounter if you used the SDK's capabilities alone.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the db configuration doing in your plugin code?

Comment: I'm trying to save some data in different database. I need dbconfiguration class because in plugin code I can't use configuration file.

Comment: Why not build an api that you can call through rest. Seems much easier than trying to do all these things in a plugin.

Comment: Thank you for this, glad you ignored all the other comments and got this sorted out. You're my hero of the day @user7 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to set database initializer to null

```
Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
```